# Is Blender Cycles rendering, killing my CPU?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am using blender on and off, and I just checked the cpu temperature history and its high was 108 degrees for an laptop.  I also just used a desktop that used 98.9% of the cpu when in cycles render view, and not even rendering images.

Eevee seems to keep the cpu at low levels currently. If I continue to use cycles will it kill the CPU? How can I reduce the load/damage etc, as a cooler for a laptop is not practical.  Or do I just have to stay with eevee from now on, as I would not like to replace the cpu every couple of years or so?

Comment: This is intended, as most users (like me) want to render things as fast as possible, and so use as much of the cpu as they can. I think there is a way to limit the amount of CPU an application can use on the system level, which you should look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles, by nature, is very realistic at the cost of computer power. I frequently have to click my fans into full gear when rendering Cycles, just to not go over 80˚C.

If using a cooler is simply out of the question than I suggest you reduce the number of threads Cycles uses. This *may* reduce the strain enough that your temperature stays within a reasonable range.

The thread count can be found under **properties>render>performance>threads**:

[image: image of thread control location]

Other than that you could try baking, rendering at a lower resolution, and simplifying your geometry. As for the temperature itself, 100˚ Fahrenheit isn't hot, but I made the assumption that you are talking Celsius.

As a last note, I believe it's worth mentioning that entering render mode in the 3d viewport, is nearly as hard on your computer as just rendering images, with the main performance difference being modifiers hidden from view, and lower view samples.